# How can I have a swipe to navigate for a stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I want to allow users to be able to swipe to navigate to a screen similar to Instagram ( swiping left takes you to your messages, the animation follows the velocity of the swipe, if you hold touch and swipe slowly screen moves a long) in a stack navigator.

I don't want to nest a bottom/top navigator to do this. I was able configure the transitionConfig prop to a similar animation, but the animation is triggered and is not responsive to the gesture( slowly swiping makes it slowly show the next screen etc..) It only works perfectly when you swipe to go back, but not to navigate to a new screen.

P.S I want to use a stack navigator to do this, not a scrollable view or something similar

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  bottomNavigator,
  Profile: Profile,
  tempScreen: TempScreen
}, {
    transitionConfig: (prop) => NavigationConfig(prop)
  })
```

Here's the animation returned by NavigationConfig

```
const trackFromRightToLeft = {
    transitionSpec: {
        duration: 350
    },
    screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
        const { position, layout, scene } = sceneProps
        const thisSceneIndex = scene.index
        const width = layout.initWidth

        const translateX = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex, thisSceneIndex + 1],
            outputRange: [width, 0, -width]
        })

        const slideFromRight = { transform: [{ translateX }] }

        return slideFromRight
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pager from  [react-native-gesture-handler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/) not exactly what you wanted but with some logic you can achive it